# opencv SIFT/SURF: output best match from one to many comparison

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, sift, multiple-matches

Im using the matching to many images sample with opencv [here's original version](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images.cpp)

Im struggling to understand the code, I'm simply looking to calculate and output the image that has the most/best matches.

What I thought was I could use for example

```
`if(queryDescriptors.rows == trainDescriptors.rows)
{
imshow(bestmatch, Mat of this trainimage);
}`
```

But I'm unsure how I acquire that specific image from the vector of Mat's?

Thank you

Comment: An explanation for the down vote would at least help..

Comment: Please refer to a the original paper to understand the details! The matching is not correct in that way!